# What is the best way to approach creating a document with many subsections?

Tags: sectioning, sections-paragraphs

I'm trying to make a document that needs to be structured with 5 sublevels, where every single sentence in the document needs to have a label in front of it such as 1.2.4 or 1.4.5.6.4. What is the best approach to doing this (I know it doesn't look great but it is what I need). Also, I would like to keep control over each level to the extent shown in the sample code.

What I have done is use the `article` document class and format `paragraph` and `subparagraph` to essentially give me `subsubsubsection` and `subsubsubsubsection`.

Is there another way to do this? As of right now the entire document has no text, only section headings, which appears as I want it to but I was wondering if there is a better method.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{titlesec} 
\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\fontfamily{phv}\fontsize{13}{16}\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}
{\normalfont\fontfamily{phv}\fontsize{12}{14}\selectfont}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}
{\normalfont\fontfamily{phv}\fontsize{12}{14}\selectfont}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\titleformat{\paragraph}
{\normalfont\fontfamily{phv}\fontsize{12}{14}\selectfont}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subparagraph}
{\normalfont\fontfamily{phv}\fontsize{12}{14}\selectfont}{\thesubparagraph}{1em}{}

\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{1.5ex}{1.5ex}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{30pt}{1.5ex}{1.5ex}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{60pt}{1.5ex}{1.5ex}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}{100pt}{1.5ex}{1.5ex}
\titlespacing*{\subparagraph}{120pt}{1.5ex}{1.5ex}


\begin{document}

\section{Hello}
\subsection{Hello}
\subsubsection{Hey There}
\paragraph{Yes sir}
\subparagraph{Good morning}

\end{document}
```

Edited to show current state:
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{depth}
\setcounter{depth}{1}
\newcounter{pi}
\newcounter{pii} [pi]  \renewcommand\thepii{\thepi.\arabic{pii}}
\newcounter{piii}[pii] \renewcommand\thepiii{\thepii.\arabic{piii}}
\newcounter{piv} [piii]\renewcommand\thepiv{\thepiii.\arabic{piv}}
\newcounter{pv}  [piv] \renewcommand\thepv{\thepiv.\arabic{pv}}


\def\psetdepth#1#2\relax{%
\ifx+#1\relax\addtocounter{depth}{#2}%
\else\ifx-#1\relax\addtocounter{depth}{-#2}%
\else\setcounter{depth}{#1#2}\fi\fi}

\newcommand\sentence[2][+0]{%
  \par
  \psetdepth#1\relax\relax
  \vspace{\csname pspace\roman{depth}\endcsname}%
  \hspace{\csname phspace\roman{depth}\endcsname}%
  \hangindent=\csname pindent\roman{depth}\endcsname
  \hangafter=1
  \indent\refstepcounter{p\roman{depth}}\llap{\csname thep\roman{depth}\endcsname\ }%
  {\csname pstyle\roman{depth}\endcsname#2\par}}

\newcommand\phspacei{20pt}
\newcommand\phspaceii{40pt}
\newcommand\phspaceiii{65pt}
\newcommand\phspaceiv{100pt}
\newcommand\phspacev{140pt}

\newcommand\pindenti{5ex}
\newcommand\pindentii{10ex}
\newcommand\pindentiii{15ex}
\newcommand\pindentiv{23.5ex}
\newcommand\pindentv{32.5ex}

\newcommand\pspacei{15pt}
\newcommand\pspaceii{15pt}
\newcommand\pspaceiii{10pt}
\newcommand\pspaceiv{10pt}
\newcommand\pspacev{10pt}

\newcommand\pstylei{\Large\bfseries}
\newcommand\pstyleii{\bfseries\itshape}
\newcommand\pstyleiii{\normalfont}
\newcommand\pstyleiv{\normalfont}
\newcommand\pstylev{\normalfont}

\begin{document}
\raggedright

\sentence{This is a sentence.}

\sentence{This is another sentence. Just like any other sentence one would think but perhaps not.}


\sentence[+1]{This sentence is similar to the others, but longer. This sentence is similar to the others, but longer.This sentence is similar to the others, but longer.}


\sentence{This is a sentence.This sentence is similar to the others, but longer.This sentence is similar to the others, but longer.This sentence is similar to the others, but longer.}


\sentence[+1]{This is another sentence.This sentence is similar to the others, but longer.This sentence is similar to the others, but longer.This sentence is similar to the others, but longer.}


\sentence[+1]{This sentence is similar to the others, but longer.This sentence is similar to the others, but longer.This sentence is similar to the others, but longer.This sentence is similar to the others, but longer.}


\sentence{This is a sentence.This sentence is similar to the others, but longer.This sentence is similar to the others, but longer.This sentence is similar to the others, but longer.}

\sentence{This is another sentence.This sentence is similar to the others, but longer.This sentence is similar to the others, but longer.This sentence is similar to the others, but longer.}

\sentence{This sentence is similar to the others, but longer.}

\sentence[+1]{Hey there how is it going my good friend. Hey there how is it going my good friend.}

\sentence[-2]{This is a sentence hey.}

\sentence{This is another sentence.}

\sentence{This sentence is similar to the others, but longer.}

\sentence[-1]{This is a sentence.}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You could have a look at KOMA-script [`scrjura`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/scrjura?lang=en) package: it is initially intended for documents such as contracts or laws, but... a document *"where every single sentence in the document needs to have a label in front of it"* looks pretty much like a contract or a law, right?

Comment: To Christian, sorry I'm not sure I understand. I'm not looking for more levels of depth. Ebo yeah, I will take a look at that package.

Comment: Why not nested `enumerate` environments,  with convenient list parameters?

Comment: @Elijah: Misread your question. But I don't recommend such labelling at all.

Comment: Haha nor would I, but it is required for what I'm doing unfortunately

Comment: latex suppresses page breaking after a section heading so I'm surprised that a document with just headings and no text works at all? (That could be fixed, but your question seems to imply it's working already)

Comment: I was actually just going to ask about that. With how it's structured right now I had to put a command like \newline in, otherwise really long sections would run off the bottom of the page or creep into the footer. I am pretty new to latex (a few days) and the main reason I actually asked the question was because I really don't want to have page break manually.

Comment: That's why it's always best to put a complete test document in your question (as i just did in my answer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are aiming for a minimal scheme with essentially just numbered sentences with minimal formatting, you can have very minimal markup in the document.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{depth}
\setcounter{depth}{1}
\newcounter{pi}
\newcounter{pii} [pi]  \renewcommand\thepii{\thepi.\arabic{pii}}
\newcounter{piii}[pii] \renewcommand\thepiii{\thepii.\arabic{piii}}
\newcounter{piv} [piii]\renewcommand\thepiv{\thepiii.\arabic{piv}}
\newcounter{pv}  [piv] \renewcommand\thepv{\thepiv.\arabic{pv}}
\newcommand\pdown{\addtocounter{depth}{1}\setcounter{p\roman{depth}}{0}}
\newcommand\pup{\addtocounter{depth}{-1}}
\makeatletter
\begin{document}


\everypar{%
\refstepcounter{p\roman{depth}}\llap{\csname thep\roman{depth}\endcsname\ }}




This is a sentence.

This is another sentence.

\pdown
This sentence is similar to the others, but longer.


This is a sentence.

\pdown
This is another sentence.

\pdown
This sentence is similar to the others, but longer.


This is a sentence.

This is another sentence.

This sentence is similar to the others, but longer.

\pup
\pup
This is a sentence.

This is another sentence.

This sentence is similar to the others, but longer.

\pup
This is a sentence.

\pdown
This is another sentence.

This sentence is similar to the others, but longer.


This is a sentence.

\pdown
This is another sentence.

This sentence is similar to the others, but longer.


This is a sentence.

This is another sentence.

\pup
This sentence is similar to the others, but longer.

\pdown
This is a sentence.

This is another sentence.

\pup\pup
This sentence is similar to the others, but longer.


This is a sentence.

\pdown
This is another sentence.

This sentence is similar to the others, but longer.


\end{document}
```

---

If you want customisable fonts and spacing I would use a scheme more like the following. You can move a sentence up or down a level with relative values such as `[+1]` or `[-1]` or jump to a specific level such as `[1]` to get back to a top level. You can specify a vertical space command an a font (or colour or whatever) command at each level.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{depth}
\setcounter{depth}{1}
\newcounter{pi}
\newcounter{pii} [pi]  \renewcommand\thepii{\thepi.\arabic{pii}}
\newcounter{piii}[pii] \renewcommand\thepiii{\thepii.\arabic{piii}}
\newcounter{piv} [piii]\renewcommand\thepiv{\thepiii.\arabic{piv}}
\newcounter{pv}  [piv] \renewcommand\thepv{\thepiv.\arabic{pv}}


\def\psetdepth#1#2\relax{%
\ifx+#1\relax\addtocounter{depth}{#2}%
\else\ifx-#1\relax\addtocounter{depth}{-#2}%
\else\setcounter{depth}{#1#2}\fi\fi}

\newcommand\sentence[2][+0]{%
  \par
  \psetdepth#1\relax\relax
  \vspace{\csname pspace\roman{depth}\endcsname}%
  \indent\refstepcounter{p\roman{depth}}\llap{\csname thep\roman{depth}\endcsname\ }%
  {\csname pstyle\roman{depth}\endcsname#2\par}}


\newcommand\pspacei{\baselineskip}
\newcommand\pspaceii{.5\baselineskip}
\newcommand\pspaceiii{.5\baselineskip}
\newcommand\pspaceiv{0pt}
\newcommand\pspacev{0pt}

\newcommand\pstylei{\Large\bfseries}
\newcommand\pstyleii{\bfseries\itshape}
\newcommand\pstyleiii{\normalfont}
\newcommand\pstyleiv{\normalfont}
\newcommand\pstylev{\normalfont}

\begin{document}
\raggedright





\sentence{This is a sentence.}

\sentence{This is another sentence.}


\sentence[+1]{This sentence is similar to the others, but longer.}


\sentence{This is a sentence.}


\sentence[+1]{This is another sentence.}


\sentence[+1]{This sentence is similar to the others, but longer.}


\sentence{This is a sentence.}

\sentence{This is another sentence.}

\sentence{This sentence is similar to the others, but longer.}

\sentence[-2]{This is a sentence.}

\sentence{This is another sentence.}

\sentence{This sentence is similar to the others, but longer.}

\sentence[-1]{This is a sentence.}


\sentence[+1]{This is another sentence.}

\sentence{This sentence is similar to the others, but longer.}


\sentence{This is a sentence.}


\sentence[+1]{This is another sentence.}

\sentence{This sentence is similar to the others, but longer.}


\sentence{This is a sentence.}

\sentence{This is another sentence.}

\sentence[-1]{This sentence is similar to the others, but longer.}


\sentence[+1]{This is a sentence.}

\sentence{This is another sentence.}

\sentence[-2]{This sentence is similar to the others, but longer.}


\sentence{This is a sentence.}


\sentence[+1]{This is another sentence.}

\sentence{This sentence is similar to the others, but longer.}


\end{document}
```

Comment: That is awesome. Also sorry about that, this is my first post. I attached a sample code to my question above. Is there anyway using the method you just wrote to control specific levels of depth in the same way that I was doing using \titleformat and \titlespacing?

Comment: @Elijah yes or no...  I went for this very minimal markup as I thought you were aiming for more or less plain text but with numbered sentences. if you want font and spacing changes I would use a syntax that has the text in a command argument `\anything{....}` as that makes it clearer and much easier to define. Once you have that markup there is no need to use the `\everypar` trick to automatically add the numbering. so the answer becomes more or less completely different:-) I may post a version later but I'll leave it a bit, see if someone else wants to post an answer in a different style.

Comment: I would very much appreciate that as I'm not entirely sure what you mean

Comment: @Elijah answer updated

Comment: horizontal space? also for any latex counter `\thexxx` is supposed to print its value, if you redefine `\thepii` as in your comment every line will be labeled with a length instead of the counter??

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I figured out how to implement the spacing I was looking for, sort of. I attached a picture at the end of my original question of what I currently have as well as the code. The only problem now is, as seen in 2.1, if the text is longer than a line then the next line is too far left, I want the whole paragraph to be in line starting from the same spot.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle nevermind I think I have finally figured something out that seems to work. I put the final code and a picture at the bottom of my question. Let me know if you see any issues and thank you for your help.