# Generating a \tableofcontents in the article class without using standard \section s

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning

Is there a way to generate a `\tableofcontents` in the article class without using standard `\section` s, but a different "`\section`" numbering scheme was used? Specifically, see the second portion of David Carlisle's answer to [What is the best way to approach creating a document with many subsections?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/362675/what-is-the-best-way-to-approach-creating-a-document-with-many-subsections). The standard `\tableofcontents` doesn't seem to work. I am new to LaTeX but I was surprised by that seeing as `\label` and `\ref` worked perfectly fine.

Edit: I would like to be able to create a table of contents containing, for example, the first or first and second level of headings (like how \setcounter{tocdepth}{2} appears to work). Below is the code referenced above:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{depth}
\setcounter{depth}{1}
\newcounter{pi}
\newcounter{pii} [pi]  \renewcommand\thepii{\thepi.\arabic{pii}}
\newcounter{piii}[pii] \renewcommand\thepiii{\thepii.\arabic{piii}}
\newcounter{piv} [piii]\renewcommand\thepiv{\thepiii.\arabic{piv}}
\newcounter{pv}  [piv] \renewcommand\thepv{\thepiv.\arabic{pv}}


\def\psetdepth#1#2\relax{%
\ifx+#1\relax\addtocounter{depth}{#2}%
\else\ifx-#1\relax\addtocounter{depth}{-#2}%
\else\setcounter{depth}{#1#2}\fi\fi}

\newcommand\sentence[2][+0]{%
  \par
  \psetdepth#1\relax\relax
  \vspace{\csname pspace\roman{depth}\endcsname}%
  \hspace{\csname phspace\roman{depth}\endcsname}%
  \hangindent=\csname pindent\roman{depth}\endcsname
  \hangafter=1
  \indent\refstepcounter{p\roman{depth}}\llap{\csname thep\roman{depth}\endcsname\ }%
  {\csname pstyle\roman{depth}\endcsname#2\par}}

\newcommand\phspacei{20pt}
\newcommand\phspaceii{40pt}
\newcommand\phspaceiii{65pt}
\newcommand\phspaceiv{100pt}
\newcommand\phspacev{140pt}

\newcommand\pindenti{5ex}
\newcommand\pindentii{10ex}
\newcommand\pindentiii{15ex}
\newcommand\pindentiv{23.5ex}
\newcommand\pindentv{32.5ex}

\newcommand\pspacei{15pt}
\newcommand\pspaceii{15pt}
\newcommand\pspaceiii{10pt}
\newcommand\pspaceiv{10pt}
\newcommand\pspacev{10pt}

\newcommand\pstylei{\Large\bfseries}
\newcommand\pstyleii{\bfseries\itshape}
\newcommand\pstyleiii{\normalfont}
\newcommand\pstyleiv{\normalfont}
\newcommand\pstylev{\normalfont}

\begin{document}

\raggedright

\sentence{This is a sentence.}

\sentence{This is another sentence. Just like any other sentence one would think but perhaps not.}


\sentence[+1]{This sentence is similar to the others, but longer. This sentence is similar to the others, but longer.This sentence is similar to the others, but longer.}


\sentence{This is a sentence.This sentence is similar to the others, but longer.This sentence is similar to the others, but longer.This sentence is similar to the others, but longer.}


\sentence[+1]{This is another sentence.This sentence is similar to the others, but longer.This sentence is similar to the others, but longer.This sentence is similar to the others, but longer.}


\sentence[+1]{This sentence is similar to the others, but longer.This sentence is similar to the others, but longer.This sentence is similar to the others, but longer.This sentence is similar to the others, but longer.}


\sentence{This is a sentence.This sentence is similar to the others, but longer.This sentence is similar to the others, but longer.This sentence is similar to the others, but longer.}

\sentence{This is another sentence.This sentence is similar to the others, but longer.This sentence is similar to the others, but longer.This sentence is similar to the others, but longer.}

\sentence{This sentence is similar to the others, but longer.}

\sentence[+1]{Hey there how is it going my good friend. Hey there how is it going my good friend.}

\sentence[-2]{This is a sentence hey.}

\sentence{This is another sentence.}

\sentence{This sentence is similar to the others, but longer.}

\sentence[-1]{This is a sentence.}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can write basically anything to the `ToC`. After all, it's a separate TeX file 'only'. Standard like content is written with `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{your content}`, more freedom is available with `\addtocontents` and even more freedom with `\@writefile`

Comment: It would be nice if you would have a minimal version of your code that is compilable or shall we copy over the code from the linked question? That's tedious

Comment: what do you want the table of contents to say (as you have no section titles) just `section-number....page-number` ?

Comment: Not to mention \l@section and \l@subsection.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer My apologies, I added the code above.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I added in a small part to the question to make it clearer. Sorry, I am trying to get out of the habit of asking incomplete questions. Items labelled as 1 or 1.1 are basically like headings in the document.

Comment: Should be easily doable with [`etoc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ToC` can generated with `\addcontentsline` and a mapping of the toc-levels to the `depth` counter value.

The code

```
\ifcase\c@depth
 \or
  \def\tocstyle{section}
  \or 
  \def\tocstyle{subsection}
  \or
  \def\tocstyle{subsubsection}
  \or
  \def\tocstyle{paragraph}
  \or
  \def\tocstyle{subparagraph}
\fi
```

defines the `\tocstyle` macro depending on the value of `depth`, where `1` means `section` etc.

The  line `\addcontentsline{toc}{\toclevel}{\protect\numberline{}#2}` adds the line to the ToC and generates `hyperlinks`, if needed when using `hyperref`.

Setting `tocdepth` to the value of `2` will allow only the first two levels as with normal sectioning levels.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{depth}
\setcounter{depth}{1}
\newcounter{pi}
\newcounter{pii} [pi]  \renewcommand\thepii{\thepi.\arabic{pii}}
\newcounter{piii}[pii] \renewcommand\thepiii{\thepii.\arabic{piii}}
\newcounter{piv} [piii]\renewcommand\thepiv{\thepiii.\arabic{piv}}
\newcounter{pv}  [piv] \renewcommand\thepv{\thepiv.\arabic{pv}}


\def\psetdepth#1#2\relax{%
\ifx+#1\relax\addtocounter{depth}{#2}%
\else\ifx-#1\relax\addtocounter{depth}{-#2}%
\else\setcounter{depth}{#1#2}\fi\fi}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\sentence[2][+0]{%
  \par
  \psetdepth#1\relax\relax
  \vspace{\csname pspace\roman{depth}\endcsname}%
  \hspace{\csname phspace\roman{depth}\endcsname}%
  \hangindent=\csname pindent\roman{depth}\endcsname
  \hangafter=1
  \indent\refstepcounter{p\roman{depth}}\llap{\csname thep\roman{depth}\endcsname\ }%
  \ifcase\c@depth
  \or
  \def\tocstyle{section}
  \or 
  \def\tocstyle{subsection}
  \or
  \def\tocstyle{subsubsection}
  \or
  \def\tocstyle{paragraph}
  \or
  \def\tocstyle{subparagraph}
  \fi
  {\csname pstyle\roman{depth}\endcsname#2\addcontentsline{toc}{\tocstyle}{\protect\numberline{\csname thep\roman{depth}\endcsname}#2}\par}} 
\makeatother

\newcommand\phspacei{20pt}
\newcommand\phspaceii{40pt}
\newcommand\phspaceiii{65pt}
\newcommand\phspaceiv{100pt}
\newcommand\phspacev{140pt}

\newcommand\pindenti{5ex}
\newcommand\pindentii{10ex}
\newcommand\pindentiii{15ex}
\newcommand\pindentiv{23.5ex}
\newcommand\pindentv{32.5ex}

\newcommand\pspacei{15pt}
\newcommand\pspaceii{15pt}
\newcommand\pspaceiii{10pt}
\newcommand\pspaceiv{10pt}
\newcommand\pspacev{10pt}

\newcommand\pstylei{\Large\bfseries}
\newcommand\pstyleii{\bfseries\itshape}
\newcommand\pstyleiii{\normalfont}
\newcommand\pstyleiv{\normalfont}
\newcommand\pstylev{\normalfont}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\raggedright

\sentence{This is a sentence.}

\sentence{This is another sentence. Just like any other sentence one would think but perhaps not.}


\sentence[+1]{This sentence is similar to the others, but longer. This sentence is similar to the others, but longer.This sentence is similar to the others, but longer.}


\sentence{This is a sentence.This sentence is similar to the others, but longer.This sentence is similar to the others, but longer.This sentence is similar to the others, but longer.}


\sentence[+1]{This is another sentence.This sentence is similar to the others, but longer.This sentence is similar to the others, but longer.This sentence is similar to the others, but longer.}


\sentence[+1]{This sentence is similar to the others, but longer.This sentence is similar to the others, but longer.This sentence is similar to the others, but longer.This sentence is similar to the others, but longer.}


\sentence{This is a sentence.This sentence is similar to the others, but longer.This sentence is similar to the others, but longer.This sentence is similar to the others, but longer.}

\sentence{This is another sentence.This sentence is similar to the others, but longer.This sentence is similar to the others, but longer.This sentence is similar to the others, but longer.}

\sentence{This sentence is similar to the others, but longer.}

\sentence[+1]{Hey there how is it going my good friend. Hey there how is it going my good friend.}

\sentence[-2]{This is a sentence hey.}

\sentence{This is another sentence.}

\sentence{This sentence is similar to the others, but longer.}

\sentence[-1]{This is a sentence.}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am getting an interesting error that I can't figure out. When I use this code instead of the similar code before, using \footnote seems to no longer work. For example adding \footnote{Hello} in the first \sentence{This is a sentence.\footnote{Hello}} like that gives the error "Use of \@xfootnote doesn't match its definition".

Comment: @Elijah: Your example did not contain `\footnote` ;-) Most likely, a `\protect\footnote` will cure this problem

Comment: Haha my bad I didn't know at the time. Should I post that as a new question?

Comment: @Elijah: Have you tried `\protect\footnote`?

Comment: Sorry just saw that, I will give it a shot

Comment: Perfect, it works. Thanks for the second answer.